# Alternative characterization of connectivity spaces.

Tags: general-topology

First, a barrage of definitions.

Define that a relation on a set $X$ is a subset of $X^2$. If $f$ is a symmetric relation on $X$, define that $f$ is *connected* if and only if there do not exist disjoint and exhaustive $A, B \subseteq X$ and non-empty relations $\alpha,\beta$ on $A$ and $B$ respectively such that $f = \alpha \cup \beta$.

Given a collection of sets $\mathcal{J}$, define the that overlap relation is the set $$\mathcal{J}^{\mathrm{ov}} = \{(A,B)|A,B \in \mathcal{J}, A \cap B \neq \emptyset\}.$$

Finally, define that a *connectivity space* is a pair $(X,\mathcal{K})$ with $\mathcal{K} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ such that

1. $\emptyset \in \mathcal{K}$
2. For all non-empty $\mathcal{J} \subseteq \mathcal{K}$ such that $\bigcap \mathcal{J} \neq \emptyset,$ it holds that $\bigcup \mathcal{J} \in \mathcal{K}$.

(Note: It is typical to call the elements of $\mathcal{K}$ "connected sets." Also, I presume that the set of all connected relations on a set $X$ forms a connectivity space; however, this is tangential to the issue.)

Question: Suppose we replaced condition 2 in the definition of a connectivity space with the following.

2.* For all non-empty $\mathcal{J} \subseteq \mathcal{K}$ such that $\mathcal{J}^{\mathrm{ov}}$ is connected, it holds that $\bigcup \mathcal{J} \in \mathcal{K}$.

Is the resulting definition equivalent to the original?

Comment: Every relation satisfies your definition of "connected" -- just take $A = \emptyset$, $B = X$.  And the definition *feels* like it's describing something disconnected.  Furthermore, you don't use the definition in the rest of your question.  Are you sure you've transcribed everything correctly?

Comment: Thanks, thats probably why i was finding the question so hard! Can you look over my "fixed" definition and let me know if it works?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment since I thought you weren't using the definition of connected relation, but now I see you use it in reference to $\mathcal{J}^{ov}$.  Unfortunately I can no longer edit my comment.

Comment: Its no big deal. Anyway, i feel bad that i screwed up the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we show $(2^\ast) \rightarrow (2)$:

Assume $(2^\ast)$, and let $\mathcal{J} \subset \mathcal{K}$ be arbitrary, but such that $\bigcap \mathcal{J} \neq \emptyset$.  We can conclude $\bigcup \mathcal{J} \in \mathcal{K}$ if we can show that $\mathcal{J}^{ov}$ is connected.  We're assuming that $\bigcup \mathcal{J} \neq \emptyset$, so $\mathcal{J}^{ov} = \mathcal{J}^2$, i.e. the "full" relation on $\mathcal{J}$.  It's not hard to see that this relation is connected; let's extract this as a:

**Lemma**: if $S \neq \emptyset$ is a set, then $S^2$ is connected.
**Proof**: Suppose not, and let $A, B, \alpha, \beta$ witness this.  $A, B$ are non-empty, so let's pick elements from them, say $a, b$.  Clearly $(a,b) \in S^2$, but it's impossible for $(a,b) \in \alpha \cup \beta$ since $\alpha \subset A^2$, $\beta \subset B^2$, and $A, B$ are disjoint from one another.

Now $(2) \rightarrow (2^\ast)$:

Let $\mathcal{J}$ be such that $\mathcal{J}^{ov}$ is connected.  We'll apply Zorn's Lemma to see that $\bigcup \mathcal{J}\in\mathcal{K}$.  Let 
$$\mathbb{P} = \left\{ \mathcal{I}\subset\mathcal{J}\ |\ \bigcup \mathcal{I}\in\mathcal{K}\right\}$$

And partially order $\mathbb{P}$ by inclusion.  $\mathcal{P}$ is not empty: for any $J \in \mathcal{J}$, $\mathcal{I} = \{J\}$ witnesses the non-emptiness.  Every chain in $\mathbb{P}$ has an upper bound in $\mathbb{P}$: this follows from your observation about nested collections of connected sets, which follows immediately from $(2)$.  Thus by Zorn's Lemma $\mathbb{P}$ has a maximal element.  Let's pick one and call it $\mathcal{I}$.  I claim that $\mathcal{I} = \mathcal{J}$ (and so $\bigcup\mathcal{J}\in\mathcal{K}$, as desired).

Suppose not.  Case 1: there is some $J\in\mathcal{J}\setminus\mathcal{I}$ such that $J\cap\bigcup\mathcal{I}\neq\emptyset$.  If that were the case, then by $(2)$, $\{J\}\cup\bigcup\mathcal{I}\in\mathcal{K}$, but then $\{J\}\cup\mathcal{I}\in\mathbb{P}$, contradicting the maximality of $\mathcal{I}$.  Case 2: Every $J\in\mathcal{J}\setminus\mathcal{I}$ is disjoint from $\bigcup\mathcal{I}$.  This also yields a contradiction, for $A=\mathcal{I}$, $B=\mathcal{J}\setminus\mathcal{I}$ witness that $J^{ov}$ is disconnected.

Comment: Are you sure its false? Consider three pairwise overlapping sets whose mutual inersection is empty. According to both definitions, their union is an element of $\mathcal{K}$. Its immediate from 2*, but slightly non-trivial from 2.

Comment: Good point. The counterexample I had in mind is wrong; but it made me think of a better one. If you have collection $\mathcal{J}\subset\mathcal{K}$ of $n$ sets, each intersecting the next so they form a "chain", then $(2^\ast)$ forces their union to belong to $\mathcal{K}$ too. Does $(2)$ force the same fact? As you suggest, yes, but non-trivially. First apply $(2)$ to get that the union of the first two of the sets is in $\mathcal{K}$. Apply $(2)$ again to get that the union of the first three is in. Continuing you get $\bigcup\mathcal{J}\in\mathcal{K}$. Now what if $\mathcal{J}$ is infinite?

Comment: Good point. Perhaps adding closure with respect to unions of nested collections would fix the problem...

Comment: As in, the union of a nested collection of connected sets is a connected set.

Comment: Actually, its possible that 2 already implies this.

Comment: Pf. Consider a nested collection of connected sets. Choose a nonempty element to be a least element of a new collection. By 2, the union of the new collection is connected.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure if this was homework.  I can give more than a hint if not.

Comment: Its not homework!

Comment: So are you still convinced it's false? I'm beginning to think it might be true.

Comment: Yes, I'm so sorry, don't know what I was thinking.  I'm beginning to think it's true too, and I'm editing my answer.  Apologies again for leading you astray.

Comment: It's no big deal! I've had fun.

Comment: Let me see if I can get a proof that it's true before I say anything more that sounds conclusive.

Comment: Is it true that a non-empty relation is connected if and only if there is a finite path between two elements that appear in the ordered pairs of the relation? If so, a proof by induction should be pretty easy.

Comment: Or perhaps not so easy. Consider a set $A$ that is pairwise overlapping with every element of a collection $\mathcal{N},$ (intuitively, $\mathcal{N}$ consists of its "neighbours" in the overlap relation). Can we use 2 to prove that $A \cup \bigcup\mathcal{B}$ is connected?

Comment: What are $\mathcal{N}$ and $\mathcal{B}$?

Comment: lol woops. Let me rephrase that. Consider a connected set $A$ that is pairwise overlapping with every element of a collection $\mathcal{N}$ is connected sets. Can we use 2 to prove that $A \cup \bigcup \mathcal{N}$ is connected?

Comment: Cool! This is the first time I've seen Zorn's Lemma in action, btw.

Comment: Yes.  Intuitively, we could build up that huge union by starting with $A$, and adding elements of $\mathcal{N}$ one at a time, making sure our union "so far" is always connected.  If $\mathcal{N}$ were uncountable, this "one at a time" process would have to be a transfinite induction, and would presume a well-ordering on $\mathcal{N}$.  We would use $(2)$ to establish the inductive case, namely that at each stage our union "so far" really is still in $\mathcal{K}$.  It would end up being a bit of a messy inductive proof, but it lends itself to a slick application of Zorn's Lemma.

Comment: Yeah, you read my mind - but Zorn's Lemma clearly does the job better, though. To be honest, I'm having trouble following the last paragraph of the argument. We assume that $\mathcal{I} \neq \mathcal{J}$. This seems not to imply that $\mathcal{I} \subseteq \mathcal{J}$, so what does $\mathcal{J} \setminus \mathcal{I}$ mean?

Comment: $\mathcal{I}$ is a (maximal) element of $\mathbb{P}$, all of whose elements are, by definition, subsets of $\mathcal{J}$.

Comment: A little bit more help? How do $A = \mathcal{I}, B = \mathcal{J}\setminus I$ witness that $\mathcal{J}^{\mathrm{ov}}$ is disconnected? What are $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: Oh I get it. Because every $J \in \mathcal{J} \setminus \mathcal{I}$ is disjoint from $\bigcup \mathcal{I}$, it follows that for all $J \in \mathcal{J} \setminus \mathcal{I}$ and all $I \in \mathcal{I}$, the sets $I$ and $J$ are disjoint.

Comment: Yup, you got it.  And so $\alpha = A^{ov}$, $\beta = B^{ov}$.